# Is it possible to change the width of a table with CSS while printing?

Tags: css, printing

I need to change the width of the table while printing the page using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/reportPrint.css" media="print" />
```

Can I change the width of the table while printing from the CSS file?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a print stylesheet to set additional CSS properties when printing, by adding into the head element:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Then in the print.css file, set out your additional/different properties, e.g.:

```
table {
   width:80em;
}
```

edit: original post had invisible code until edit after I posted, so I don't know if this answers your question.

Comment: +1, Very nice piece of information! Didn't know this even though I work in web publishing software projects.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you want to override inline CSS in the HTML markup. Do this:

```
#divShowTable {
    width:100%!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use print media query:

Example:

```
@media print {
  .print-table {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```